# Redshift not inserting data properly

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have data type as `decimal(18,4)`, through copy command I am inserting json into redshift table. For the value `0.13` it is inserting properly but for the value `0.1475` is it inserting as `0.1474`.

Comment: We might lose precision when loading numbers from data files in JSON format to a column that is defined as a numeric data type. Some floating point values are not represented exactly in computer systems. As a result, data you copy from a JSON file might not be rounded as you expect. To avoid a loss of precision `Represent the number as a string by enclosing the value in double quotation characters`,`Use ROUNDEC to round the number instead of truncating` and `Instead of using JSON or Avro files, use CSV, character-delimited, or fixed-width text files`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most accurate representation of **0.1475** in **IEEE754** standard for Double is

`1.47499999999999992228438827624E-1`   (similar but with less digits for **Float**)

Redshift uses (either Float or Double) internally before slotting the number into the column with defined precision (of 4 in your case) and does not apply rounding but simply trims the result to 4 decimal places.

Only values of `X + Y/(2^N)` will appear precise, which you can test. For 4 decimal places the best value is **1/16 = 0.0625**

Therefore you have to pass **ROUNDEC** option when using `copy` as per docummentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-roundec)

Comment: Can you explain `Only values of X + 1/(2^N) will appear precise, which you can test. For 4 decimal places the best value is 1/16 = 0.0625`

Comment: Actually the fraction should be `Y/2^N` (corrected the answer). Only fractions like `1/2, 1/4, 3/4 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8, 1/16, ... 1/32` have precise binary representations. Any other fraction will have imprecise binary representation with infinite number of fractional digits. Just like for us using decimal fractions `1/3 == 0.(3),  2/3 == 0.(6)` and only fractions of kind `Y/10^N` can be represented using finite number of decimal places.

Comment: *Redshift uses (either Float or Double) internally before slotting the number into the column with defined precision...* it's not that I don't believe you - I have been trying to find documentation on this without luck. Is there any?